# Display 600 records on one page but it takes long time to load page in php?

Tags: php, mysql

**I want to show 600 records on one page but it takes long time to load the page in PHP**

```
while($row= $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

**How may I solve this loading issue?**

```
foreach($rows as $row){
    $qty="";
    //print_r($row);
    //echo "<br/>";
    if(isset($row['mastr_id'])){
        $id = $row['mastr_id'];
        //$addsql.="id='".$vendorid."',";
     }  
     if(isset($row['vendor_id']) && $row['vendor_id']!=""){
         $vendorid = $row['vendor_id'];
         $addsql.="vendor_id='".$vendorid."',";
      }       
  $addsql=substr($addsql,0,-1);
 }
```

Comment: So show less records.

Comment: Why build the $rows array - generate the output in the loop where you're reading the query results.

Comment: Or... Hire a faster server?

Comment: I can't understand your code. Can you post the php code rendering the page and your original SQL query?

Comment: i tried without $rows array but it takes 16 to 20 seconds to load page @SloanThrasher

Comment: I have to show 500 records on single page @u_mulder

Comment: @sloanthrasher do you think it makes much difference? I'm not sure, but I suspect not.

Comment: Is getting the data from the database the problem then? Have a look at `EXPLAIN` to see whether you'd like to have more indices

Comment: Is the loop through $rows building the where clause for a SQL statement? I just noticed that you are using a var named $addsql in the loop. Something is missing from what you are showing us. Unless you have the slowest server on Earth, there's no way it takes that long to go through 600 rows. Edit your question and show the rest of the code.